# slideUp Div and html columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to accomplish what it appears on the following picture(bottom of the post). I'm just working on the top part where the search fields are. I have several questions;
1) is this the correct why to make columns on html?
2) How can I accomplish to put the icon in the center of the div with that grey line, I tried to put border to the div of the form and puts in a weird place. Also when I add the button with the arrow it puts it all the way to the right. It needs to be always in the center even if i resize the screen

```css
#searchForm{
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 18%;
  width: 100% !important;
}
.column1{
  
}
.column2{

}
.column3{

}.column4{
  
}
.columns{
  margin-right: 50px;
  maring-left: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left; 
}
.searchValue{
  width: 200px;
  height: 2.1em;
  margin-bottom: 19px;
}
.mySelects{
   -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
   height: 2.4em;
  width: 200px;
}
.radioButtonsSearch{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.btns{
  background-color: #14477E;
  color: #FFE45E;
  width: 150px;
  height: 2.4em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.sliderUp{
  background-color: #14477E;
  color: #FFE45E;
  width: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: 2.4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: 
  margin-left: 60%;
}
```

```html
<section class="">
  <center>  
    <form id="searchForm">
          <div class="column1 columns">
            <div class="radioButtonsSearch">
              <input type="radio" name="searchType"  value="house" checked>House
              <input type="radio" name="searchType"  value="house">Repair parts<br/>
            </div>
              Mile Post Number<br/>
            <input type="text" name="milePost" class="searchValue" placeHolder="Enter the mile post number" />
          </div>
          <div class="column2 columns">    
            Project Number<br>
            <input type="text" name="projectNumber" class="searchValue" placeHolder="Enter the project number" /><br/>
            Serial Number<br/>
            <input type="text" name="serialNumber"  class="searchValue" placeHolder="Enter the serial number" /><br/>
            <button class="btns">Search</button>
          </div>
          <div class="column3 columns">       
            House Size<br/>
            <select class=" mySelects searchValue">
              <option value="volvo" disabled selected>Select one</option>
              <option value="volvo">4x4</option>
              <option value="saab">6x6</option>
              <option value="opel">8x8</option>
            </select><br/>
            Start Date<br/>
            <input type="text" name="serialNumber"  class="searchValue" placeHolder="Enter the serial number" /><br/>
            <button type="input" class="btns">Clear</button>
          </div>
          <div class="column4 columns">       
            Status<br/>
            <select class="searchValue mySelects" style="line-height: 24px;">
              <option value="volvo" disabled selected>Select one</option>
              <option value="volvo">Hold</option>
              <option value="saab">xxx</option>
              <option value="opel">xxx</option>
            </select><br/>
            Asset ID<br/>
            <input type="text" name="assetID" class="searchValue" placeHolder="Enter the asset ID" /><br/>
          </div>  
        </form>
    <br>
  </center>
</section> 
<button class="sliderUp">^</button>
```

here's my demo

This is what I'm trying to accomplish
[wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh4GR.png)

Thanks!

Comment: if you just a column structure you can use a table to maintain similar sizes, or flexboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into flexbox for grid layouts. Browser support is growing, and auto prefixers are becoming more and more common.

With flexbox you will be able to easily horizontally and vertically center whatever you want.

Here's a good [tutorial](http://flexboxfroggy.com/) to get you started.

Comment: I can't user any library. Everything has to be native. The only library I'm allowed to use is jQuery, but for HTML and CSS just plain

Comment: @TamoDevelopers flexbox is part of CSS3

Answer (score 0):

1) your columns work perfectly fine for what you are doing. If you don't mind learning new techs try looking at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). It is very popular at the moment and will handle screen resizing automatically while allowing break points for moving elements (lets say you are on mobile and want there to be only one column instead of two, you can do that!, although you can always create a mobile specific web page that gets loaded if on mobile.)

2) This probably isn't the best way to do this but you can get the line with your image like such:

```html
<div width=100%>
  <hr width=45%; style="display:inline-block">
  <button style="display:inline-block" class="sliderUp">^</button>
  <hr width=45%; style="display:inline-block">
</div>
```

Inline styles just for easy viewing.

Hope this helps!